# bind delegate event on element when loaded

Tags: jquery

How can I trigger an event when an item is loaded dynamically?

I have an html page that loads iFrames. I only have access to the parent html page and the dynamically loaded element is located on the iframe.

When i try something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( document ).on( "click", "#link1", function() {
        alert( "link loaded" ); 
    });
});
```

I can see the alert when the `link1` is presses. But what I want is to bind the event when the element becomes visible for the first time.

I tried to use something like the following but it fails:

```
$( document ).on( "load", "#link1", function() {
  alert( "link loaded" ); 
});
```

PS: When the iframe is loaded it does some ajax loading stuff, and then the `link1` appears. So I cannot bind the event on iframe.load()

Comment: You could use observers or mutation events, but browser support for each is very limited. Generally there's little to no reason to write code this way, it's better to instead run code or trigger an event when the event that generates the link happens.

Comment: @KevinB i can only use IE :(

Comment: Run your code in the success of the "ajax loading stuff". that's what i was hinting at in my first comment.

Comment: if you mean that iframe and link are generated after some ajax ran, then see MackieeE comment below my post on how to find dynamically added iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply use of `load()` function?

```
$(function(){
    $('#myIframe').load(function(){
        $(this).show();
        alert('link loaded');
    });
});
```

or I misunderstood your problem?

Comment: If the `myIframe` isn't found because it was dynamically added, you'd need to use `$(document).find('#myIframe').load(function(){}` But I'm un-sure if it's the `<a>` or the `<iframe>` that's been dynamically added.

Comment: @MackieeE +1 for the note